# C++ Model View Design

Tags: c++, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am currently struggling with the design of an application of the visualization and manipulation of sensor data. I have a database that contains several STL-containers with measured data in it.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::array<uint16_t, 3366>> data1;
std::unordered_map<std::string, QImage> data2;
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<Point3D>> data3;
```

I also have different Views (mostly Qt-based) and each view should be associated with a model which is specific to one of the data sets. So data1 is supposed to be processed and manipulated in a class called model1 which is then displayed by means of a class view1 and so forth.

But I cant seem to find a suitable design structure to incorporate this idea. the models grant access to their processed data, but that data is contained in different container structures as given above. That makes it unfeasible to use inheritance with a pure virtual function in the base class like

```
std::map<...,...> getModelData() = 0;
```

The initial idea of this inheritance was to avoid code duplication but that doesnt seem to be the right solution here. I know that Qt in their "Model-View" concepts makes use of their QVariant class to have maximum flexibility in terms of types being returned. However, I am wondering, what is the best solution with standard C++ here? I read a lot about striving for loose-coupling, code reuseability, Dependendy Inversion and how to favour composition over inheritance but I do have problems putting these theoretical advise into practice and end up with code bloat and repetitive code most of the times. Can you help me?

Comment: does your code currently working? can you provide your current architecture? and if all the data have different view, there probably have little benefit to do this.

Comment: It sounds like you have code that does the same things but to different types (those types happen to be containers). That sounds like a job for templates.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give more code but so far, I can give a few hints:

-Can you use QMap instead of std::unordered_map ? It is more agile if you need to tangle with a UI

-Maybe make your second argument of the list a common base type like (code not tested, treat as pseudo code)

```
class BaseDataClass
{
  public:
    int getType();
    QImage* getImageData();
    std::array<uint16_t, 3366>>& getArray();
    std::vector<Point3D>>& getVector();
  private:
    int mType;
    BaseDataClass(); //hide ctor or make abstract, as you wish
}
```

You can avoid code duplicating with this. Make three new classes that each inherit from BaseDataClass. You can then make a method that iterates over all BaseDataClass, checks the type (e.g. 1=QImage; 2 = array ; 3 = vector), and exectues the right method according to the type (get QImage from all type 1`s ...). You also can cast the pointer to the right type then. Which makes it even better if your derived classes gain more and more functionality (like sorting or validating data)

Comment: thank you, I want to resort to the stl as much as possible. My code base is too large to post it here I guess